# How to handle the Internal server error? Nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

How to handle the error so that if the user does not provide a token, then an UnauthorizedException is thrown.

At the moment I am getting this error:

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

**ts:**

```
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    try {
      const jwt = request.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

      if (!jwt) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException('Token is not provided.');
      }

      return this.jwtService.verify(jwt);
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: is `request.headers.authorization` `undefined`? from where this internal server error came from??

Answer (score 0):

You can try to recreate auth module from the documentation.
Or try to console.log() on each line.

By default, JWT internal module works well. It can encode and decode all that you need automatically.

https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication

Answer (score 0):

I use a middleware for this purpose. I'll share a basic version of it.

`auth-middleware.ts`

```
import {HttpStatus,Injectable,Logger,LoggerService,NestMiddleware,} from '@nestjs/common';
import { NextFunction } from 'express';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class AuthMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(
    private readonly authenticationService: AuthService, 
// (I use Firebase auth. You can inject JWT service here instead)
    private readonly logger: LoggerService, // Good'ol logger
  ) {}
  public async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    // Checks if req has authorization header
    const header = req.headers['authorization'];
    if (!header) {
    // If no headers are present, returns a 401.
    // I use problem+json
    // Thats why you are seeing more fields in the response instead of just a 
    // code and message
      return res
        .status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
        .json({
          title: 'Unauthorized',
          detail: 'Invalid Token',
          type: 'https://app-site.com/login',
          status: HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
          instance: 'login/null',
        })
        .setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/problem+json');
    }
    // Splitting "Bearer token" to ["Bearer","token"]
    const token = header.split(' ')[1];
   // Validating token with auth service
   // It returns a "tuple" for me...you can have it return whatever you want
    const [
      authClaims, // Custom claims that is extracted from the JWT
      result, // JWT Validation result (boolean)
      authProviderUid, // Firebase UID
    ] = await this.authenticationService.verifyToken(token);
    if (
      !result || // If JWT is invalid
      authClaims.accountStatus === AccountStatusList.Banned ||
      authClaims.accountStatus === AccountStatusList.Suspended
    ) {
      // You shall not pass
      return res
        .status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
        .json({
          title: 'Unauthorized',
          detail: 'Invalid Token',
          type: 'https://app-site.com/login',
          status: HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
          instance: 'login/null',
        })
        .setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/problem+json');
    }
    // Attaches the claims, result and UID with req for the next middleware(s)/controller
    req['authResult'] = { authClaims, result, authProviderUid };
    //Reassuring 
    this.logger.log('Token verified', AuthMiddleware.name);
   // next function from express
    next();
  }
}
```

Next, In the module(s) your controllers are declared,

`api.module.ts`

```
import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module, NestModule, RequestMethod, } from '@nestjs/common';

@Module({
  imports: [
    //...
  ],
  controllers: [
    AuthController,
    ProfileController,
    SubscriptionController
  ],
  providers: [
    //...
  ],
})
export class ApiModule implements NestModule {
  public async configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(AuthMiddleware)
      // Exclude some paths
      .exclude({ path: '/api/v1/auth/sign-up', method: RequestMethod.POST })
      .forRoutes( // Your controller classes you want to run the middleware on
        ProfileController,
        SubscriptionController,
        AuthController
      );
  }
}
```

*How it works*

Every request goes through the specified middleware (if path not excluded). If the request is unauthorized, throws an error before it reaches the controller.

If the request is at the controller, the request is authenticated. You have to take care of the authorization part with guards etc...

Authentication and Authorization are different.

I'd suggest to use middleware for authentication and guards for authorization.

Links :

1. [NestJS Middleware Documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware#middleware)
2. [Problem Details](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807)